# Program crashes when using my strupr implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, toupper

I have written my implementation of strupr function from string library. When I call this function, the program crashes. I have already found an another way to make it working but I am wondering why this verion isn't working. Program crashes exactly during executing the `*str = (*str) - 32;` instruction.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char * my_strupr(char * str)
{
    char * result = str;

    while(*str != '\0')
    {
        if(*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z') *str = (*str) - 32;
        str ++;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char * str = "some text";
    cout << my_strupr(str);
    return 0;
}
```

I have to use pointers in this case, they are required in my task.

Comment: Post the calling code - you are probably attempting to modify a string literal.

Comment: I have already added.

Comment: A classic one: `char * str = "some text";` -> `char  str[] = "some text";`

Comment: @MichaelWalz You're right. It helped and the function don't crash the program anymore. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is storing the string in read-only memory, and you are getting a seg-fault trying to modify this memory.
This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45684424/can-a-string-literal-and-a-non-string-non-compound-literal-be-modified)